# gunicorn ImportError: No module named webob

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn, webapp2

I run an appengine project by using:

`gunicorn -b $3000 main:app`

It is a python (Django) project and i am running it on linux.

The exact error is:

```
[2020-01-17 11:30:04 +0000] [4551] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2020-01-17 11:30:04 +0000] [4551] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (4551)
[2020-01-17 11:30:04 +0000] [4551] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-01-17 11:30:04 +0000] [4556] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4556
[2020-01-17 11:30:04 +0000] [4556] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 375, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/home/vicktree/Desktop/noah/web/noahs-app/main.py", line 37, in <module>
    import webapp2
  File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.1/webapp2.py", line 25, in <module>
    import webob
ImportError: No module named webob
[2020-01-17 11:30:04 +0000] [4556] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4556)
[2020-01-17 11:30:04 +0000] [4551] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2020-01-17 11:30:04 +0000] [4551] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I have webob and i do not know why i am getting this error.  I have tried to pip install webob.

Comment: standard environment?

Comment: Can you please add more information. As Dan mentioned, can you tell us what environment are you using. Also can you post your app,yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using appengine, you have to specify it under the libraries directive in the app.yaml

`libraries:
- name: webob
  version: "1.1.1"`

Check the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27
for using a built-in third-party library bundled with the runtime.